# Android Studio AVD screen is in wrong position

Tags: android, android-studio, android-virtual-device

I created a Nexus 6 avd. The position of the screen is completely in wrong position.

[image]

And here is the setting. My skin setting is Nexus_6

[image]

What did I do wrong here?

**UPDATE:**
The Android Studio log said: "emulator: emulator window was out of view and was recentered"

I found a solution here, by setting windows.x in emulator-user.ini. However, every time I start AVD, it automatically changes these values.

Comment: Why don't you use genymotion fastest emulator